# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'tblProje'

Tags: t-sql

I am getting this error message when running this sql statement in ssms:

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'tblProje'

This is the statement itself:

```
PRINT 'Updating FileSetId data from Table Project to Table tblProject'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE  tblProject set tblProject.ProjectFileSetId = Project.FileSetId
FROM Project
WHERE tblProject.AccountingProject = Project.Project_Id'
IF EXISTS(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Project' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FileSetId')
BEGIN
execute sp_executesql @SQL
END
GO
```

I am trying to make the statement so that it can run as many times as possible. Basically checking to make sure that a column exists before trying to update from it. I cannot tell where this error is coming from

Comment: `NVARCHAR(100)` is presumably not long enough and you are getting truncation. Try `select len('UPDATE  tblProject set tblProject.ProjectFileSetId = Project.FileSetId
FROM Project
WHERE tblProject.AccountingProject = Project.Project_Id')`

Comment: Yes that seemed to have solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you take your query and look at the length, you will see an issue:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE  tblProject set tblProject.ProjectFileSetId = Project.FileSetId
FROM Project
WHERE tblProject.AccountingProject = Project.Project_Id'

select len(@sql)

select len('UPDATE  tblProject set tblProject.ProjectFileSetId = Project.FileSetId
FROM Project
WHERE tblProject.AccountingProject = Project.Project_Id')
```

Your variable assignment is cutting off 41 chars at the end so it is not valid SQL to execute when you run `sp_executesql`.  Change your variable to something like `NVARCHAR(4000)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and it will work.

```
PRINT 'Updating FileSetId data from Table Project to Table tblProject'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE  tblProject set tblProject.ProjectFileSetId = Project.FileSetId
FROM Project
WHERE tblProject.AccountingProject = Project.Project_Id'
IF EXISTS(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Project' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FileSetId')
BEGIN
execute sp_executesql @SQL
END
GO
```